# MySQL select all info for child item

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a product table like this

```
+----------+------+-----------------+-------+-------+
| ParentID | SKU  |       Name      | Price | Color |
+----------+------+-----------------+-------+-------+
|        1 |  qwe | Product 1 Red   |     12| Reb   |
|        1 |  qaz | Product 1 Blue  |     13| Blue  |
|        1 |  erf | Product 1 Green |     11| Green |
|        2 |  tgb | Product 2 Black |     12| Black |
|        2 |  yhj | Product 2 White |     12| White |
|        3 |  ujk | Product 3 Red   |     15| Red   |
|        3 |  kjm | Product 3 Blue  |     19| Blue  |
|        3 |  gfd | Product 3 Pink  |     17| Pink  |
|        3 |  vgy | Product 3 White |     16| White |
|        3 |  njk | Product 3 Black |     10| Black |
|        4 |  cfg | Product 4 Red   |     12| Red   |
+----------+------+-----------------+-------+-------+
```

What i would like is a query to get one item for each parentid with all that items info. I dont care which specific row, but it should have all the info for that row and only one per parentid

I need to be left with something like this

```
+----------+------+-----------------+-------+-------+
| ParentID | SKU  |       Name      | Price | Color |
+----------+------+-----------------+-------+-------+
|        1 |  qaz | Product 1 Blue  |     13| Blue  |
|        2 |  yhj | Product 2 White |     12| White |
|        3 |  gfd | Product 3 Pink  |     17| Pink  |
|        4 |  cfg | Product 4 Red   |     12| Red   |
+----------+------+-----------------+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
Select t.* from table t, 
(select parentId, min(price) as price
from table
group by parentId) a
where t.parentId = a.parentId
and t.price = a.price
```

**UPDATE:**

```
SET @rownum := 0;

select min(b.rank), b.parentID, SKU,Name ,Price, Color from (
select @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank, parentID, SKU,Name ,Price, Color
from t1) b
group by b.parentID
```

Link to **[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b5979/23)**

Comment: alfasin, what would happen if there would be 2 child items with the same price. I dont think this would work.